# Content in HeaderText attribute of ValidationSummary control rendered incorrectly

Tags: asp.net, html

I have the following validation summary control in the markup:

```
<asp:ValidationSummary ID="vsValErrs" CssClass="errors" HeaderText="<div><%# TranslatedMessage%></div>" runat="server" />
```

where TranslatedMessage is a property defined in the code behind. The problem is that the validation summary control gets rendered as

```
<div id="vsValErrs" class="errors" style="color:Red;">
    <div>
        <!--[CDATA[<%# TranslatedMessage%-->
        ]]&gt;
    </div>
</div>
```

which causes the content to be rendered incorrectly, probably because the **]]>** part is outside the comment block. Why does this happen?

For those who are wondering, the reason for having a div in the HeaderText attribute is because I'm using it to style the header text (using a CSS selector that selects the first div,  in the errors class); it's probably not best practice but this is the only way I've come up with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try by setting headertext property value in pageload event like

```
protected void Page_Load(..)
{
..
ValidationSummury1.HeaderText="<div>"+TranslatedMessage+"</div>";
}
```

If translated message is not available then put it into session varible and set it to HeaderText property.

Comment: That did the trick! Can't believe I didn't think of that... thanks!